# Can spacetime be curved even in absence of any source?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, vacuum

Einstein's equation in absense of any source (i.e., $T_{ab}=0$) $$R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R=0$$ has the solution $$R_{ab}=0.$$

But I think $R_{ab}=0$ does **not** imply that all components of the Riemann-Christoffel curvature tensor $R^c_{dab}$ be zero (or does it?). From this can I conclude that spacetime can be curved even in absence of any source?

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity) ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. But I wonder under what condition $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ will also imply a flat space. No source anywhere? See my comment at Charlie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical meaning of non-trivial solutions of vacuum Einstein's field equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87332/physical-meaning-of-non-trivial-solutions-of-vacuum-einsteins-field-equations). See also this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105336/96768

Comment: @Thiago Thanks. These are helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why gravitation propagates from sources....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking about is referred to as a [vacuum solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Vacuum_field_equations) to the field equations. This does not mean that there is no mass *anywhere*, rather that we are considering a region of our curved spacetime in which there is no mass.

The Schwarzschild solution for instance is a "vacuum solution" because we are considering the region *outside* of the central mass in which there is no matter, but in which the curvature is non-zero.

You are correct that the vanishing of the components of the Ricci tensor does *not* imply the vanishing of the components of the full Riemann tensor. $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ is a vacuum solution, ${R^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}=0$ is flat spacetime.

Comment: I see. So the source enters via boundary conditions? Can I, therefore, draw the conclusion that if there is no source anywhere $R_{ab}=0\Rightarrow R^c_{dab}=0$?

Comment: @mithusengupta123:  You'd also have to make some kind of assumption about the behavior of the metric at infinity (timelike, spacelike and null.)  For example, a solution with a plane gravitational wave traveling through space is a valid vacuum solution (just like a plane EM wave is a solution to Maxwell's equations with $J_a = 0$.)

Comment: I think I have to delve deeper into the details of it to understand things better. Thanks for the answer and comments though :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple answer:

I would view this in the same light as the following question:

*Does*

$$ {\bf \nabla \cdot E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$

*imply zero electric field in region with no charge density?*

To which the answer is clearly, "No".

And as an example: The astronauts on the moon. They were there in a pretty good vacuum dropping feathers and hammers, which then took off on like geodesics.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. $R_{ab}=0$ does not imply $R^{a}_{bcd}=0$. For one thing, $R_{ab}$ has 10 components (in $n=4$ dimensions), whereas $R^{a}_{bcd}$ has $20$ components. The simplest example I can think of is Schwarzschild solution, which has $R_{ab}=0$ everywhere but $R^{a}_{bcd}\neq0$. If you allow the inclusion of a cosmological constant, then the de Sitter metric is an example of an empty solution with non-trivial spacetime curvature. As pointed out here

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105336/96768

A spacetime containing gravitational waves is empty but with non-trivial Riemann tensor.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. But it doesn't mean that the curvature is from nowhere. The Field equation describes the curvature (locally) at a point only from $T_{\mu \nu}$ at the same point (Since it's all built in a differential manifold and tangent spaces at each points aren't related to each other). If $T_{\mu \nu}$ is zero at a point, then you end up deriving a vacuum solution.